# How do you install the latest version of Xuggler (5.4, as of 18/05/2013) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, xuggler

I have literally no clue where to start doing this. I've downloaded the necessary Jar's from the site, and done some research on how to install Xuggler in Eclipse, and everything is outdated or irrelevant.

My system is a 64-Bit Windows 8. Most things that worked in vista and windows 7 should be compatible with my system as long as they are also 64-bit compatible.
All I would like to be able to do is obviously run an application with it in Eclipse.

Any advice, helpful explanations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can download Xuggler 5.4 [here](https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/)

and some more jar to make it work...

[commons-cli-1.1.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/download_cli.cgi)

[commons-lang-2.1.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

[logback-classic-1.0.0.jar](http://logback.qos.ch/download.html)

[logback-core-1.0.0.jar](http://logback.qos.ch/download.html)

[slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

You can check which dependencies xuggler needs from [here](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/ivy.xml):

Add this jars and xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar to your project's build path and it s ready.

**version numbers may change

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated! What do i have to do with the dependency file, do i have to put it somewhere? Sorry I have no experience with Ivy or Maven

Comment: you dont need to do something with that. I just write it to show xuggler needs that dependencies. Just add these jars to your build path and xuggler is ready

Comment: Where abouts do you get the additional JAR's, I'm probably overlooking something obvious on the download page.

Comment: I added some links to the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: after downloading these jar is there any code to run it.

Comment: Not all of the mentioned jars are needed. In fact, just using the Xuggler library will work fine. Logback and slf4j are used by Xuggler to handle logging: you'll need them to get debug info, but Xuggler will also run without them. Commons-CLI is only required if you're compiling Xuggler itself, not if your using the pre-compiled jar in another project.

Comment: @ayalcinkaya I added above dependencies in my project but still getting same error. Can you please check my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490599/could-not-open-output-container-for-live-stream-using-xuggler-youtube-broadcas

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

For people who are still looking for the download link, here it is: http://web.archive.org/web/20160501013248/http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven, only add this repository:

```
  <repository>
       <id>xuggle repo</id>
       <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
```

and this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use currently this dependency and work fine.